# htaccess code for redirecting between main domain and sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a wordpress site that uses a subdomain domain for the uploads folder so it loads content faster. I'm trying to eliminate duplicate content as the subdomain points to the main domain. I want to redirect anything in that folder to the subdomain if the url, and I need everything else to point to the main domain.

I've been trying for hours but can't get the two working together and keep getting an error saying "redirected too many times".

Please write this for me someone!

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway Robert but I've fixed the problem using a different approach by assigning the uploads directory to the sub-domain via virtual host and then forcing a 404 error for anything that points to the same directory but in the main domain. Because the sub domain uses a shorter file path I could use this 404 redirect to prevent duplicate results in the main domain:

RedirectMatch 404 ^/wp-content/uploads/.*$